# Python: How does this lambda function work?

Tags: python, lambda

I understand how basic lambda functions work as in this example:

```
def adder(x):
    return lambda y: x + y
add5 = adder(5)
add5(1) # returns 6
```

Although, I'm trying to decipher how the lambda function works in this example:

```
def secondsToStr(t):
    return "%d:%02d:%02d.%03d" % \
        reduce(lambda ll, b: divmod(ll[0], b) + ll[1:], [(t*1000,), 1000, 60, 60])
```

To my eyes the lambda function is: `lambda ll, b: divmod(ll[0], b) + ll[1:]`

How does `ll[0]` and `ll[1:]` work in this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ll` just a reference to a sequence type (maybe a list or a tuple, but could be anything that supports `__getitem__`), so that `ll[0]` is the first item of the sequence and `ll[1:]` is a list of the remaining items. The fact that `ll` is an argument to a lambda doesn't affect how `ll` is interpreted.

Comment: thank you, at first I was confused that the lambda function was calling itself, which I know doesn't make sense. I realize now that the `reduce()` function: `reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value` requires a function and sequence, which is where the sequence comes from!